# Google Assistant API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-assist-api

Is there some google assistant api guide or tutorial? I cannot find anything related by these keywords. There seems have some Android app integration guide, but I want to integrate with my cloud service, not android app.

I find IFTTT have connected Google Assistant to several services, so I want to add some intents to my custom service.

I have built an Alexa app by using Alexa Skill Kit to handle my customize intent, and want to find something similar in Google Assistant developer playground, but I have no clue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Assistant API was officially launched by Google for Windows, Mac, and Linux by which you can [Get Google Assistant on Windows, Mac, and Linux.](http://www.ytechb.com/how-to-enable-google-assistant-on-windows-mac-and-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create voice applications for Google Assistant which are called as Google actions you will have to rely on the developers guide posted [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/)

There is also an introductory course on udemy for the same.
I personally have used [dialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/)
and for the backend and I used [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and have hosted a few apps into the store

Answer (score 0):

Google Assistant will open its SDK to developers this December.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a quite a lot of development on supporting the developer ecosystem, including the release of the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/introducing-google-assistant-sdk.html), [app templates](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/apps-for-google-assistant-new-languages.html), and the [ability to host](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/assistant-codelab/index.html#0) and edit your integration via [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/).

For some code samples see

- [Conversational Components](https://github.com/actions-on-google/conversation-components-nodejs) for Google Assistant
- [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/) (previously Api.ai) [v2 Samples](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2/tree/master/samples)

Comment: Thanks, this post is kind of deprecated, it's one year ago when Google assistant just pop up.